# Setting an Instatiated button's OnClick, in order to set a gameobject variable? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*Hey guys!* First time using Stack Overflow because of the unique nature of my problem.

I am currently instantiating a button based off of how many of a gameObjects with a certain script I have in the scene. How would I go about ensuring the instantiated Button's onClick, is setting the parent script's empty gameObject var is set to the (i) gameObject (the physical turret)?

```cs
private void Start()
{
    Turret_Script[] turretsOnTank = FindObjectsOfType<Turret_Script>();

    for (int i = 0; i < turretsOnTank.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject turretButton = Instantiate(testingTurretButton, gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.transform);
        turretButton.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = turretsOnTank[i].name;
        turretButton.transform.position = new Vector3(150 + (100 * i), 330);

        //This is where I assume I'd make a button var based off of the turretButton var.

        //This is where I assume I'd change the OnClick of the button.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button you're using is `Button`, you can do it like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < turretsOnTank.Length; i++)
{
    GameObject turretButton = Instantiate(testingTurretButton, gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.transform);
    turretButton.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = turretsOnTank[i].name;
    turretButton.transform.position = new Vector3(150 + (100 * i), 330);
    turretButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListner(
        () => turretHolder = turretsOnTank[i]);
}
```

`() => turretHolder = turretsOnTank[i]` is the lambda which will set `turretHolder` field with `turretsOnTank[i]`, which `i` is the index of turret.

By the way, your code looks like it needs some reforming. `GetChild()` returns transform, so you don't neet to do `GetChild(0).gameObject.transform` to get transform. Just `GetChild(0)` would enough.

And, `transform` field is already exists in `MonoBehaviour`, so you don't need to access `transform` via `gameObject`.

And, `Instantiate` can return `Transform` type, if prefab is `Transform`. So, your code would be:

```cs
    Transform turretButton = Instantiate(testingTurretButton.transform, gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0));
    turretButton.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = turretsOnTank[i].name;
    turretButton.position = new Vector3(150 + (100 * i), 330);
    turretButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListner(
        () => turretHolder = turretsOnTank[i]);
```

Which has more less redundancy.

Comment: Your response didn't seem to work. I couldn't get either version to function as it was unable to set anything on the button or correctly compare the two options.

oof. Any other suggestions?